# How can I regulate lettuce indoors so it doesn't bolt/flower?

Tags: indoors, flowering, lettuce, bolting

Is there a science to regulating lettuce indoors in a way that prevents or minimizes bolting/flowering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control the lighting so it never exceeds 12 hrs. And keep it cool, below 70 degrees F if you can.

Why you growing it indoors though, that's not usually done.

Comment: I grow everything indoors. No bugs, no pesticides, easy access, 365 climate controls, etc.

Comment: Less than 65F/19C would be better, AFAIK.

Comment: @Ecnerwal probably, but it's the light that really tells a plant how to behave and when. The lower heat just helps some more, and the more your lower the heat in the summer, well...the greater the energy cost, which although his question doesn't ask it specifically, I know this guy is highly energy conscious.

Comment: Keep them cooler, no higher than 65F. If they start to bolt from that, keep them at 60F. Lettuce is a cool weather plant. Also, I grew lettuce hydroponically floating on my fish tanks. The seedlings got leggy because it wasn't cool enough in there.